# Detect Device to Near or away from Ear Android code

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximity

I need to know whether device is near to ear or not by using sensors

I tried using proximity, I want to combine accelerator and gyroscope sensors to exactly find the device is near or far from Ear.

Code for Proximity

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

```
    float distance = event.values[0];

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
        if (distance < mProximity.getMaximumRange()) {
            iv.setText("Near");
        } else {
            iv.setText("far");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need code sample

Comment: Why don't you use the proximity?

Comment: I want to record when device is near to ear, Its accidentally recording when some object comes near to the device

Comment: how did you try with proximity? show your piece of code

Comment: Guys Need some help here please

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html), I am sure you can dig more to get some answers to your problem, but this should be enough to get you started. You can also do some research about position sensors in android. The documentation is quite useful

```
// Create a constant to convert nanoseconds to seconds.
private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;
private final float[] deltaRotationVector = new float[4]();
private float timestamp;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
// This timestep's delta rotation to be multiplied by the current rotation
// after computing it from the gyro sample data.
if (timestamp != 0) {
    final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
    // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.    
    float axisX = event.values[0];
    float axisY = event.values[1];
    float axisZ = event.values[2];

    // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
    float omegaMagnitude = sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);

    // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
    // (that is, EPSILON should represent your maximum allowable margin of error)
    if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
      axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
    }

    // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
    // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
    // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
    // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
    float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
    float sinThetaOverTwo = sin(thetaOverTwo);
    float cosThetaOverTwo = cos(thetaOverTwo);
    deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX;
    deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY;
    deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ;    
    deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
  }
  timestamp = event.timestamp;
  float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
  SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix,
                              deltaRotationVector);
// User code should concatenate the delta rotation we computed with the current rotation
// in order to get the updated rotation.
// rotationCurrent = rotationCurrent * deltaRotationMatrix;
   }
}
```